# How can I deactivate iCloud to avoid "MobileMe Services Stopped Working" message?

Tags: icloud, windows, ms-office, mobileme

I keep getting the message *MobileMe Service Stopped Working* each time I open Outlook 2007. I have to click on the Close Program button in the error message twice each time it shows up while Outlook is trying to load up. Then I am able to use Outlook. I never use my iCloud account and would like to know how I can deactivate iCloud so I do not have issues with my Outlook.

Comment: Have you gone into the Control Panel and removed the MobileMe or the iCloud application from Windows?

If that isn't there, then to to Control Panel -> Mail(32-bit) -> Accounts and remove the account from the list that you don't want there.

I don't have a VM installed of Windows with Outlook to show you each step. Reply to this thread if you still can't get it to work. Also...what version of Windows is Outlook 2007 installed on?

Answer (score 2):

Took me a few days, but found this:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2992
That worked for me

#### Uninstalling the MobileMe Control Panel for Windows 7 and Vista

To uninstall the Control Panel, follow these steps:

- Click the Start Menu.
- Choose Control Panel from the Start Menu.
- In Control Panel, choose Uninstall a Program, which is under the Programs section (If you are using Classic view in Windows Vista, open the Programs and Features Control Panel).
- In the Programs and Features Control Panel, under the listing of Programs, select the MobileMe Control Panel.
- In Windows 7, click Change. Then, click Remove from the pop-up window. In Windows Vista, click Uninstall.
- Follow the onscreen directions to remove the MobileMe Control Panel.

#### Uninstalling the MobileMe Control Panel for Windows XP

To uninstall the Control Panel, follow these steps:

- Click the Start Menu.
- Choose Control Panels from the Start Menu.
- In Control Panel, choose Remove a Program.
- If you use Windows XP, choose Add/Remove Programs.
- In the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel, under the listing of Programs, select the MobileMe Control Panel.
- Click Uninstall, and follow the onscreen directions to remove the MobileMe Control Panel.